# Does magic ignore armor in Dragon Age RPG?

Tags: magic, armor, dragon-age-rpg

I don't find any indication that magic damage ignores armor in the spell list but then again it makes sense that at least some spells do.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Sometimes.

Magic in its entirety does not ignore Armor but there are some spells with *Penetrating Damage* which will.

**Player's Guide Pg 40 / Core Rulebook Pg 76 : Armor and Shield Details**

> When you take damage in combat, you subtract the armor rating before losing Health. This applies each time you are hit, so over time, even poor armor can prevent you from taking a lot of damage.
>
> Certain attacks, however, can bypass the effects of armor. They inflict what is called penetrating damage, which ignores armor altogether. **Armor offers no protection against penetrating damage.**

**Player's Guide Pg 50 / Core Rulebook Pg 111 : Spell Format**

> *Description*: This entry explains what the spell does in detail. **Armor protects against any damage inflicted as normal unless it is noted as penetrating damage (in which case, it ignores armor altogether).**

Comment: do you have an example of such spell? Sorry I don't have the rulebook handy at the moment

Comment: @KeenSeeker99 Lightning. Blizzard. Shock. Walking Bomb. Stonefist. Honestly, a quick glance through the spells section of the core rulebook seems to show that of the spells that actually do damage, the majority of them (but not all) are penetrating and thus ignore armour.

Comment: @OneCritWonder you should maybe clarify that your page references are to the original Dragon Age Player's Guide, which was effectively superseded by the later publication of the Dragon Age RPG Core Rulebook, which combined the Player's Guide and GM's Guide in a single book and is much more fleshed out (and in which your referenced texts are found apparently unchanged on page 76 and page 111 respectively).

Comment: @Carcer thanks man. I will check those points when I get home. I remember searching for piercing on the pdf but that seems to be the wrong key word to look for

Comment: @Carcer That's a totally valid point.  I've not kept on the system for a while and simply opened the book I do have and found the answer.  I'll have to update with the new references.